# Why does question mark show up in web browser?

Tags: browser, unicode, utf-8

I was (re)reading [Joel's great article on Unicode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and came across this paragraph, which I didn't quite understand:

> For example, you could encode the Unicode string for Hello (U+0048
>   U+0065 U+006C U+006C U+006F) in ASCII, or the old OEM Greek Encoding,
>   or the Hebrew ANSI Encoding, or any of several hundred encodings that
>   have been invented so far, with one catch: some of the letters might
>   not show up! If there's no equivalent for the Unicode code point
>   you're trying to represent in the encoding you're trying to represent
>   it in, you usually get a little question mark: ? or, if you're really
>   good, a box. Which did you get? -> �

Why is there a question mark, and what does he mean by "or, if you're really good, a box"? And what character is he trying to display?

Comment: ...years later... I just realized the author of that article is the CEO of stack overflow :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a question mark because the encoding process recognizes that the encoding can't support the character, and substitutes a question mark instead.  By "if you're really good," he means, "if you have a newer browser and proper font support," you'll get a fancier substitution character, a box.

In Joel's case, he isn't trying to display a real character, he literally included the Unicode replacement character, [U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char//fffd/index.htm).

Comment: I am using the latest version of Chrome and it shows the question mark and not the box. What "newer browser" could he be referring to? :)

Comment: I added "and font support." On what OS are you using Chrome?  I'm using Chrome on Win7, and I see the diamond with the question mark.

Answer (score 3):

It’s a rather confusing paragraph, and I don’t really know what the author is trying to say. Anyway, different browsers (and other programs) have different ways of handling problems with characters. A question mark “?” may appear in place of a character for which there is no glyph in the font(s) being used, so that it effectively says “I cannot display the character.” Browsers may alternatively use a small rectangle, or some other indicator, for the same purpose.

But the “�” symbol is REPLACEMENT CHARACTER that is normally used to indicate *data error*, e.g. when character data has been converted from some encoding to Unicode and it has contained some character that cannot be represented in Unicode. Browsers often use “�” in display for a related purpose: to indicate that character data is malformed, containing bytes that do not constitute a character, in the character encoding being applied. This often happens when data in some encoding is being handled as if it were in some other encoding.

So “�” does not really mean “unknown character”, still less “undisplayable character”. Rather, it means “not a character”.

Answer (score 1):

A question mark appears when a byte sequence in the raw data does not match the data's character set so it cannot be decoded properly.  That happens if the data is malformed, if the data's charset is explicitally stated incorrectly in the HTTP headers or the HTML itself, the charset is guessed incorrectly by the browser when other information is missing, or the user's browser settings override the data's charset with an incompatible charset.

A box appears when a decoded character does not exist in the font that is being used to display the data.

Answer (score 0):

Just what it says - some browsers show "a weird character" or a question mark for characters outside of the current known character set.  It's their "hey, I don't know what this is" character.  Get an old version of Netscape, paste some text form Microsoft Word which is using smart quotes, and you'll get question marks.

http://blog.salientdigital.com/2009/06/06/special-characters-showing-up-as-a-question-mark-inside-of-a-black-diamond/ has a decent explanation.