# How to replace question mark with pound sign (currency)

Tags: javascript

I'm returning a string from a database, but due to how the database encodes, some pound signs (£) are getting replaced by question marks. I'd like to reinstate the pound signs, but without replacing genuine question marks in the string. I've managed to write a regex to test for the combination of question mark followed by number, but I'm not sure how to do the replacement. Here's what I have:

```
var str = document.getElementById("TESTVAR").value; 
console.log(/\\?[0-9]/.test(str));
```

Comment: I'm presuming your seeing �? The `?` means you have an encoding issue. It's not an actual `?` it means the browser doesn't know how to display the icon. Your proposed solution won't work. You need to resolve the encoding issue.

Comment: See [Why does question mark show up in web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424613/why-does-question-mark-show-up-in-web-browser)

Comment: Maybe you can check the encoding of the HTML page, I advise to use UTF8. Also, when that does'nt work you can try to use a html entity `&pound;`

Comment: Unfortunately this is a work system that is quite rigid - I can't change the encoding and other users add info to the DB so I can't change £ for &pound;

Comment: You need to know what bytes are used to encode this character in the database and look for those. Or, you know, just blame the other team and make them fix it :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript you can insert special characters using one of the escape sequences. For example you can display £ using the unicode escape sequence \u00A3.

An example for replacing question marks followed by number is shown below:

```
var text = 'The price is ?56 and another price is ?90';
result = text.replace(/\?(?=\d+)/g, '\u00A3');
alert(result); //The price is £56 and another price is £90
```